# NITF File, Pixel size calculate

Tags: python, raster, gdal, nitf

what can i use instead of getgeotransform using gdal python for nitf files?
I dont access to pixel size from gdalinfo.

````
Driver: NITF/National Imagery Transmission Format
Files: file.ntf
       file.aux
       file.rrd
Size is 640, 1284
GCP Projection =
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6375837,298.259923563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0859632925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0859632925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0859632925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
GCP[  0]: Id=UpperLeft, Info=
          (0.5,0.5) -> (20.43,20.018,0)
GCP[  1]: Id=UpperRight, Info=
          (639.5,0.5) -> (39.437,30.015,0)
GCP[  2]: Id=LowerRight, Info=
          (639.5,1283.5) -> (39.377,40.989,0)
GCP[  3]: Id=LowerLeft, Info=
          (0.5,1283.5) -> (39.372,40.992,0)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That image is georeferenced by ground control points and it is not possible to tell the pixel size directly because the image is slightly rotated in EPSG:4326. I would warp the image into normal north-up image and check the pixel size from the warped image.

gdalwarp file.ntf warped.tif
gdalinfo warped.tif

A rough estimate can be done by dividing maxX-minX and maxY-minY by the image size in X direction (640) and Y direction (1284) because the ground control points seem to be at the image corners.